# React-router Redirect does not seem to work when I separate it into another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to set up a PrivateRoute component in my React app but when I separate the redirect into another file it does not seem to Redirect if Auth is false - it just hangs on the admin page with no component loaded.

When I have the PrivateRoute function inside my App.js the component works fine but when I separate it into a new file react-routers Redirect does not seem to work

Here is the function:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Redirect, Route } from "react-router-dom";
function PrivateRoute({component: Component, ...rest}) {
  const isAuth = false;
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        isAuth ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/login",
              state: { from: props.location }
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  )
}
export default PrivateRoute;
```

Here is my list of routes

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from './views/Home';
import Players from './views/Players';
import Stats from './views/Stats';
import Admin from './views/Admin';
import Nav from './components/Nav/Nav';
import SideNav from './components/SideNav/SideNav';
import Login from './views/Login';
import PrivateRoute from './components/PrivateRoute/PrivateRoute';
function App() {
  const [navState, setNavState] = useState(false);

  return (
    <Router>
      <div id="app" className="centurion-major-app d-flex">
        <main className="flex-1 main_container">
          <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
          <Route path="/players/" component={Players} />
          <Route path="/stats/" component={Stats} />
          <Route path="/login/" component={Login} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/admin/" component={Admin} />
        </main>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
export default App;
```

I know I could just leave the PrivateRoute function inside the App.js but I don't understand why it wouldn't work?

Comment: Is both the functions in same file?

Comment: No but when I add them in the same file it works - I'm just curious to why they are not working when I separate them?

Comment: Can you also post your import and export `PrivateRoute` component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think importing `BrowserRouter as Redirect` and using `<Redirect to=` doesn't work as [BrowserRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter) component is for an entirely different purpose and don't expect a `to` prop. Changing the imports to

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Redirect, Route } from "react-router-dom";
```

should fix the issue.